# How to capture URL parameter and save related data on server side

Tags: javascript

I have a landing page and I want to send landing page url with parameter that is individually identifiable to each users.  When the user click the url, I want the landing page using javascript or some other tools to save the url parameter and other information such as session length into a server side csv or sql. 
Anyone can guide me to the right method? Thanks

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. You wont't get good answers (and your question is likely to get flagged) until you get far more specific. That said, in general you'd do a POST request from client to server in which you include the specified info (often called the `payload`) The server receives the POST request unwraps the payload and does whatever it wants with it.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to provide more details on your programming stack to get good quality answers but I'm new here so bombs away. first use

```
window.location
```

object to get the URL information. for detailed examples reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

from there you would need to pass that URL information to some server side web method so that it can be stored. since you didn't specify what programming stack you're using, I'll just keep things generic.

I tend to use JQuery (but you can do it in Javascript, or other frameworks so YMMV) and call server side web methods using something along the lines of:

```
var data = window.location.href;
var url = "https://example.com/myWebService;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  ...
});
```

reference https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

The web service myWebService itself could be anything capable of writing the OS or to SQL. I'll leave that part to you since there are dozens of ways to approach that topic.